# Can the listings package automatically indent source code?

Tags: listings, indentation

The `listings` package automatically highlights keywords in source code and makes it look nice. Is it possible to automatically indent the program? For example, in `listings`, if the following code is typed,

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
printf("\n Hello World");
}
```

the output should be

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("\n Hello World");
}
```

Can `listings` to do that, and if so, how should I configure it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `listings` package provides that functionality; see subsection 5.6 of the manual. Make sure the `formats` aspect is loaded, which can be done either by passing `formats` as a package option to `listings`,

```
\usepackage[formats]{listings}
```

or by using the `\lstloadaspects` macro *after* loading the `listings` package,

```
\usepackage{listings}
...
\lstloadaspects{formats}
```

Then, use the `\lstdefineformat` macro to define a "format", i.e. instructions about what `listings` should do upon encountering certain characters. The format definition shown below is taken straight from the manual.

Be aware that this feature remains experimental; according to the manual,

> The automatic source code formatting is far away from being good. First of all, there are no general rules on how source code should be formatted. So ‘format definitions’ must be flexible. This flexibility requires a complex interface, a powerful ‘format definition’ parser, and lots of code lines behind the scenes. Currently, format definitions aren’t flexible enough (possibly not the definitions but the results).

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[formats]{listings}

\lstdefineformat{C}
{
  \{=\newline\string\newline\indent,%
  \}=\newline\noindent\string\newline,%
  ;=[\ ]\string\space,%
}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.c}
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
printf("\n Hello World");
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\section*{``Raw'' listing}
\lstinputlisting{sample.c}

\section*{With automatic formatting}
\lstinputlisting[format=C]{sample.c}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like to develop a patch for this @Jubobs

Comment: @subhamsoni Do you mean that you would like to extend that functionality? If so, that's great and I encourage you to get in touch with the maintainer of `listings`.