# Maple code in comment create with tcolorbox package

Tags: tcolorbox, maple2e

i have 4 questions:

- Insert a char like ‎\sqcup‎ between 'Hello' and 'World' in the **"Hello‎ World"**?
- How can i change code environment so that comment (not in mathmode)
  is sensitive for Maple keyword, for example, change its color?
- Is there a way for define **'smart indent'** of MATLAB software,
  automatically indents my code?if not, How can i define a command like
  **\mapleIndent** (for indent), that work in upper part, instead i insert space by hand?
  [image]
- How can i Move the lower part of Fib algorithm (last code env below)
  **together** to the middle of line? in i use **center lower**, output isn't nice format.
  [image]

the code is:

```
‎\documentclass{article}‎

‎\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}‎
‎\usepackage{tcolorbox}‎
‎\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}‎
‎\usepackage[top=2.5cm,right=3.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}‎  

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%     ‎MAPLE CODE‎
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‎\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,theorems}‎

‎\lstdefinelanguage{Maple}{‎
            ‎morekeywords={‎
            ‎and,assuming,break,by,catch,description,do,done‎,
            ‎elif,else,end,error,export,fi,finally,for,from,global,if‎,
            ‎implies,in,intersect,local,minus,mod,module,next,not,od‎,
            ‎option,options,or,proc,quit,read,return,save,stop,subset,then‎,
            ‎to,try,union,use,uses,while,xor‎
            ‎}‎,
            ‎sensitive=true‎,
            ‎keywordstyle=\color{black}‎,
            ‎morecomment=[l][\color{green!50!black}]\#‎,
            ‎morestring=[b]"‎,
            ‎morestring=[d]‎"
            ‎aboveskip={0pt}‎,
            ‎belowskip={0pt}‎,
            ‎}[keywords,comments,strings]‎

‎\makeatletter‎
‎\tcbset{every listing line/.code={%‎
  ‎\def\lst@NewLine{%‎
      ‎\ifx\lst@OutputBox\@gobble\else‎
          ‎\par\noindent \hbox{}#1%‎
      ‎\fi‎
      ‎\global\advance\lst@newlines\m@ne‎
      ‎\lst@newlinetrue}}}‎
‎\makeatother‎

‎\newtcblisting{code}[1]{‎
             ‎skin=bicolor‎,
             ‎colback=white‎,
             ‎colbacklower=white‎,
             ‎colupper=red!40!black‎,
             ‎collower=blue‎,
             ‎listing options={language={Maple}}‎,
             ‎fontupper=\ttfamily\bfseries‎,
             ‎boxrule=0mm‎,
             ‎top=0mm,bottom=0mm,middle=0mm‎,
%             ‎center lower‎,
             ‎nobeforeafter‎, 
           ‎listing and comment‎,
           ‎comment=‎{‎ #1}‎,
           ‎every listing line={\textcolor{red!40!black}{\ttfamily>‎ }}
           }

‎\newdimen\Tab‎
‎\Tab=3ex‎
‎\def\mapleIndent#1{\hbox{\hskip#1\Tab\relax}}‎

‎\begin{document}‎




‎\begin{code}{ F‎ :‎= proc()‎ "‎Hello World‎ " ‎end proc}‎
‎F‎ :‎= proc() # comment‎
     "‎Hello World‎"
‎end proc;‎
‎\end{code}‎


‎\begin{code}{}‎
‎Max‎ :‎= proc()‎
‎local i,m;‎ 
‎if nargs = 0 then‎
‎return‎ -‎infinity‎
‎end if;‎
‎m‎ :‎= args[1];‎
‎for i from 2 to nargs do‎
‎if args[i] > m then‎
‎m‎ :‎= args[i]‎
‎end if;‎
‎end do;‎
‎m;‎
‎end proc‎:
‎\end{code}‎




‎\begin{code}{‎
‎Fib‎ :‎= proc(n::nonnegint)\\‎
‎option remember;\\‎
‎\mapleIndent{1} if ‎‎$‎n < 2‎$‎ then ‎‎$‎n‎$‎ else Fib‎$‎(n‎ - ‎1)‎$‎‎ + ‎Fib‎$‎(n‎ - ‎2)‎$‎ end if\\‎
‎end proc}‎
‎Fib‎ :‎= proc( n‎ :: ‎nonnegint‎ )
     ‎option remember;‎
     ‎if ‎‎n<2‎‎ then‎
          ‎‎‎n‎‎‎
     ‎else‎
          ‎Fib‎‎(n-1)‎‎‎ + ‎Fib‎‎(n-2)‎‎‎
     ‎end if;‎
‎end proc;‎
‎\end{code}‎


‎\end{document}‎
```

Comment: For 3rd question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166680/1952